# Keras convolution along samples

Tags: keras, lstm, convolution

I have LSTM NN that has 1 output after the last Dense (softmax) neuron. I saw that if I smooth the predicted Y by applying numpy convolution, I get much better accuracy.

The issue is that I manually choose values for convolution kernel. I'd like to get NN possibility to train convolution kernel values. So, I need to add convolution as the last layer after softmax dense. If I understand Keras Conv1D correctly, it can convolve along features only. But I need to convolve along output for different samples (axis 0). Thus, if NN produces

```
Y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
```

...and kernel_size of convolution layer is 3, it should convolve vector Y and the another trained convolution vector C (for example [0.1, 0.5, 1]):

```
>>> np.convolve([0.1, 0.5, 1],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7], mode='same')
array([ 0.07,  0.23,  0.39,  0.55,  0.71,  0.87,  0.95])
```

So, the goal is convolve output along samples but let NN train convolution vector kernel to choose the best one.

Is it possible to do this in Keras?

Comment: `1 output after the last Dense (softmax)` -- Do you mean an output shaped like `(batch,1)` with softmax? This always outputs 1, no matter what.

Comment: Yes, I meant that NN has 1 dense neuron in the last layer

Comment: Then you must fix that before anything. You should probably be using "sigmoid" instead.

Comment: Ok, but regardless of activation the question left the same: how to add convolution layer that will convolve along samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convolution layer will require an input shape like `(samples, length, channels)`.

To make a convolution along the samples, you simply reorganize your tensor to make it attain the convolutional input requirements.

Looks like you want the old samples to be the new length, and that you have only one channel in any case. I'm not sure whether this is exactly what you intend to do, but as a consequence, we will leave only one new sample.

So, we reshape your tensor from `(samples,)` to `(1, samples, 1)`.

For reshaping considering the first dimension, we need a lambda layer:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x,(1,-1,1)), output_shape=(None,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(1,3,padding='same'))

#it's very important to reshape back to the same number of original samples, or keras will not accept your model:
model.add(lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x,(-1,1)),output_shape=(1,)))
```

The final shape may need adjustment to fit your training data. Depending on whether your numpy arrays are `(samples,)` or `(samples,1)`.